# Any tips regarding 'The Great Eye' encounter?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've just encountered '*The Great Eye*', last time it killed a crew member and I wounder what positive sides does it have? Any tips regarding this encounter?

> *Inside this nebula you detect a rogue planet drifting through space, on its surface a huge monolith visible at this distance even to the
>   naked eye. A Zoltan elder hails you from the planet. "Through luck or
>   intent, you have discovered **the Great Eye**. Look into its depths and
>   receive your just deserts."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose option 1, "[Pull the ship in closer](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Zoltan_%22Great_Eye%22)" one of four things can happen:

- You receive the [Healing Burst](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons#Healing_Burst) weapon
- You fight a Zoltan ship (with standard rewards for winning)
- You receive a high amount of scrap
- You loose 1 crew member. (Having a cloning bay will not prevent this loss of crew)

Assuming you are in good enough shape to fight a Zoltan ship, 3/4 are positive results from the Great Eye. If you choose option 2 and leave, nothing happens.

Comment: Does each option have 25% chance? Because 2/2 encounters ended up with a dead crew member so far.

Comment: As near as I can determine, all outcomes are equally likely. Although a [different wiki](http://ftlwiki.com/wiki/Events#Rogue_planet_with_monolith) does not list the possibility of a Zoltan ship fight, so it might be 33%. But I seem to recall this second wiki being rather inaccurate or out of date when it comes to random events.

Comment: The Zoltan ship fight exists, but there is no reason to assume that 4 outcomes means they all have a 25% probability.

Comment: @rom016 there is equally no reason to assume they *don't* mean that. I do recall reading in the past that all outcomes of random events are equally likely, however I have been unable to source this information, or validate it's accuracy. However, if you can find a reputable source or two that claims otherwise (and, ideally, provide the probabilities for the various encounters), I'd be happily edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Trent Hawkins Your answer is fine, but the comments assuming equal probability without a source are bad.